# Intellij unit test finishes with exit code -1

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

All unit tests are terminated with this message. I have tried many things including invalidating caches, reinstalling intellij, re-cloning project from vcs, reloading .m2 folder.

I have also checked test run settings but could not find anything related.

[image]

Comment: did you try to run it from gradle/maven ?

Comment: Hello, please share the little code sample to illustrate the problem. Which runner is used to run the test? Thank you

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter with junit5. There is no code sample, all tests terminate. @OlgaKlisho

Comment: Please see the following issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120628. Does it look like the duplicate of your case? Do you have System.out in code? Thanks

Comment: No. This is not the same case. Mine was finishes with exit code -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved just by recloning and running application with maven. I guess it has downloaded some libraries from the private repo which it should has already downloaded with "clean install" command in the first place but it did not work somehow.

Edit: Problem occurs again. comes out of nowhere. All test were running before 5 minutes. and 5 minutes later it finishes with exit code -1

Edit-2: It is solved! It was because junit bug.
`DefaultParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy` class has this method

```
static ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy getStrategy(ConfigurationParameters configurationParameters) {
        return valueOf(configurationParameters.get(CONFIG_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME).orElse("dynamic").toUpperCase());
    }
```

and that `("dynamic").toUpperCase()` returns **"DYNAMİC"** with Turkish locale and since class has no enum of **"DYNAMİC"**, it immediately terminates all tests.It should convert to uppercase as **"DYNAMIC"**, and to achieve that it should use English locale as default I think, not my computer locale.